# Selecionar dados de df de acordo com dados de uma lista

Tags: r, data.frame, lapply

Caros(as)
 conforme dados abaixo:

```
nr <- c(100:199)
dt <- rep("data",100)
x <- data.frame(nr,dt)
y <- c(110:115)
```

Preciso obter,
os números comuns entre a primeira coluna do data.frame x e a lista y

```
match <- x[x[1] == (lapply(x[1], function(z) which(y %in% z))),]
print(match)
```

mas tenho o erro:

```
"Warning message:
  In FUN(left, right) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

O resultado esperado deveria ser assim:

```
110 "data"
111 "data"
112 "data"
113 "data"
114 "data"
115 "data"
```

Answer (score 4):

segue código que retorna o resultado que você espera

```
match <- x[which(x$nr %in% y), ]
```

Comment: obrigado. Funcionou, vou usar no meu contexto.